# Find a String in ArrayList of objects - java

Tags: java, object, arraylist, equals

I wrote a program that consists of an ArrayList,
which contains objects.
Every object has a name.
I want to find the index in ArrayList with the same name as i would input it with scanner. I tried the following code, but it doesnt work.
    `q=0;
    while(!naziv.equals(racuni.get(q).getNaziv())) 
        q++;`

Comment: Because the array list contains two objects. The one with index 0 and another with index one

Comment: Check *q < object.size()* in the while condition

Comment: The exception message tells you exactly what's wrong: You're trying to access Index 2 and the list has only size 2! (Index 0 and 1 in the list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: i get that, but my input string is the same one as the String of the index 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2):

First let's format your code clearly

```
String name = sc.next();
int q=0;
while(q < object.size() && !name.equals(object.get(q).getName())) {
  q++;
}
```

Second, you must verify that `q` also is below the `ArrayList` size, cause it wouldn't make sense if you tried to access a position bigger than your `Array`.

Here have a sample

```
    ArrayList<Animal> object = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    object.add(new Animal("duck"));
    object.add(new Animal("chicken"));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = sc.next();
    int q = 0;
    while (q < object.size() && !name.equals(object.get(q).getName())) {
        q++;
    }
    System.out.print(q);
```

// Prints 0 if you write "duck"

// Prints 1 if you write "chicken"

// Prints 2 if you write "NotInArrayList"

Comment: It prints out exactly the same thing, if I put in the String of zero index, but if I put in the name of the first index it works

Comment: @AnaPeterka Let me test it out 1 second

Comment: @AnaPeterka Compare your version to mine and figure out what's wrong in yours. Or post more of your code for us to figure out what you did wrong. Cheers :)

Comment: I figured out that when i input another name, that name replaces the name that was there before

Comment: @AnaPeterka That doesn't happen in my code. Again, try out my code, or post the rest of your code for we to analyze what's wrong in yours

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to solve this problem in JAVA8 is by using **Stream**

If element is available in list, it prints the first index of element, else returns -1.

```
OptionalInt findFirst = IntStream.range(0, objects.size())
.filter(object-> objects.get(object).getName().equals(nextLine))
.findFirst();
System.out.println(findFirst.isPresent() ? findFirst.getAsInt() : -1);
```